# spark filtering not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter some values on my Dataframe[Row]. The problem is the following:

```
var index : Int = 0
var set = SetBuilding(features, 3)
val soglia : Int = 30
var exit : Boolean = false

while (!exit && index<set.length){
 val attributes = set(index).split(",")
 var r = scala.util.Random
 var i = r.nextInt(attributes.length)
 var previousI = i
 var j : Int = 8
 var maxprojections : Int = 5 
 var dataframe = sqlContext.sql("SELECT "+set(index)+" FROM table").cache()
println("**************VALUTAZIONE SOTTOINSIEME: "+ set(index)+"***********************" )

 while ( j!=0 && maxprojections >=0){

var filtered = dataframe.filter((elem : Row) => ReturnType(elem.get(elem.fieldIndex(attributes(i)))).>(soglia))
println ( "proiezione su attributo " + attributes (i))
for (elem <- filtered){
  println(elem)
}
if ( attributes.size != 1){
 do{
   i = r.nextInt(attributes.length)
 }while ( i == previousI )
}
     println ( "*********valore di previousI = "+ attributes(previousI)+ "******************************")

 previousI = i

 j = filtered.count().toInt   
 println ( "*********valore di j = "+ j+ "******************************")
 maxprojections = maxprojections - 1
 println ( "*********valore di maxproj = "+ maxprojections+ "******************************")
}
 index+=1
 if ( index >= 4)
   exit = true
}
```

The problem is that if I maintain my data structure as a spark.DataFrame and I call filter(),on some attributes I expect an empty dataframe to be returned  but calling filteredData.count the value is != 0, but I'm sure that those values are less then threshold.

The problem does not occurs when I call collect() on filteredData.

Is there a solution that includes maintaining **filteredData** as a **DataFrame**?

I Hope now the query is well posed

Comment: I think that you need to add some more of the code to let us understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: not really. I would be more interested in seeing this: "I put this line into a while cycle"

Comment: "calling filteredData.count the value is != 0, but i'm sure that those values are less then threshold. The problem does not occurs when i call collect() on filteredData." Are you saying that the size of collection returned by collect() is 0, even though the value returned by count is not 0?

Comment: Could you comment on what do you want to achieve in general? What is the purpose of the program?

Comment: the purpose just filtering some values from the dataframe. one of the stop criterias is thant when the dataframe returned is empity the program should stop. But when i expect it to be empity it actually isnt so and when i expect it to be not empity it is. its quite a strange thing i really cant figure it out

Comment: @SiLaf yes that's actually the problem

Comment: Do you expect each filter in the loop to remove values from the previous `Dataframe` in the loop? That is, would you expect the loop to do something similar to: `dataframe.filter(attibute1 > threshold).filter(attribute2 > threshold).filter(attribute3 > threshold)...`?

Comment: @maasg precisely

Comment: That's the issue! Each dataframe represents an immutable set of data. Let me explain in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the expection in the context of the question is that each `filter` operation would mutate the `Dataframe` effectively removing elements from it.

That's an incorrect assumption.

Each dataframe represents an immutable set of data. 
On each iteration of the loop, we are obtaining a new dataframe that's the result of filtering using a single condition.
So at each loop the result looks like:

```
/** loop 1 **/ var filtered = dataframe.filter(attibute_1 > threshold)
/** loop 2 **/ var filtered = dataframe.filter(attibute_2 > threshold)
...
/** loop n **/ var filtered = dataframe.filter(attibute_n > threshold)
```

What we are observing at the end is the result of the final filter operation overwriting the variable `var filtered = dataframe.filter(attibute_n > threshold)`  All other filter operations are lost.

If we would want to iteratively remove elements in this context, the quick change to achieve that would be to stack the filters in the loop by exploiting the mutable variable. Like this:

```
var filtered = dataframe
while (cond) {
    filtered = filtered.filter(attibute_i > threshold)
}
```

Here the resulting `filtered` dataframe has a logical plan composed of the several filter operations following each other.
It will be equivalent to: `dataframe.filter(attibute1 > threshold).filter(attribute2 > threshold).filter(attribute3 > threshold)...`

Comment: yeah i follow you, but i can't figure put what is the difference between your solution and my code, if i look at it i see the filtering operation repeated on the same dataframe (as you propose in your solution) into a while cycle with a condition. isnt it? The second issue is that the code works but in revers: if the dataset is empty count operation returns me a value different from 0, if the datase if full it returns 0. I'm really getting crazy with this sh*t

Comment: @vsam490 `dataframe`s are immutable. What's is mutable in this context is the reference, in this case `filtered`. The difference with your version is that the mutable reference is being updated every time. It's the same difference between:  `var b = a + 1`(yours)  and ` a = a + 1` (mine). Let's say that we start with `a=0 and b=0`  in a loop of 100 times. As result, the first expression will be `b = 1` while the second will be `a = 100`.

Comment: @vsam490 that said, there're probably better ways to express your algorithm than using mutable variables. Mutability should be avoided when possible, specially in the context of distributed data processing.

Comment: got it.  How ever i tried as you sad, but ther's alway the same problem. i modified the code as follows:
 var filtered = data

    while ( j!=0 && mp >=0){

    
    filtered = filtered.filter((elem : Row) => 

ReturnType(elem.get(elem.fieldIndex(attributes(i)))).>(soglia))

...

}

Comment: @vsam490 I suppose that the result has to be different between the two versions, no? Otherwise, the trouble might be in the `ReturnType(...)` expression in the filter always returning true.

Comment: please help me @maasg, i've done as you suggested ad i noticed that now ther's another issue: i applyed the filtering action as you suggested but after filtering couple of times my var filtered, and after calling filtered.count instead of seeing his dimensions decrease, i see them increasing. How is that possible?